# Using fs=$'\n' on array does not produce use newlines between entries

Tags: arrays, bash

I am using the following bash code to either include newlines or spaces when printing array elements.  I am using `fs=$'\n' || fs=' '` that works when using `${aggr[j]` inside a loop, but not when using `${aggr[*]`.

```
nl=3 
nk=$((nl-1))
aggr=("$@")
rst=$(tput sgr0)
ctp=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 39)

nmline=1 
(( nwline == 1 )) fs=$'\n' || fs=' '
printf '%s%s' "${ctp}${aggr[*]:0:nk}${rst}" "$fs"
```

Comment: Don't you want `IFS` to change behavior of `${array[*]}`? And variables that change behavior of the shell itself are all upper case (by POSIX convention, so lower case variables can be safely used without unintentionally changing shell behavior). But here you _want_ to change shell behavior, so you need to change a variable in that reserved space.

Comment: It is not that I do not want it.  But I am inquiring why things are not working out when coding things as mentioned.

Comment: Neither `FS` nor `fs` is a special variable in `bash`. `FS` is an *`awk`* variable used to define how `awk` separates input and output fields.

Comment: `fs=$'\n'; printf "%s%s%s" 'a' "${fs}" 'b'` generates `a\nb`, ie, it works for me; on the otherhand ... `(( nwline == 1 )) fs=$'\n' || fs=' '` generates an error for me: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token $'fs=\'\n\'`; I'm assuming you want to `&&` the test and the first assignment, eg,  `(( nwline == 1 )) && fs=$'\n' || fs=' '` ... ???

Comment: You are right, I need the `&&`.

Comment: Instead of changing IFS, you could just use `printf "%s$fs"  "${ctp}${aggr[@]:0:nk}${rst}"`. `aggr` will be split, and `$ctp` and `$rst` concatenated to the first and last value respectively. Then printf prints each argument with a trailing `$fs`. Names like `reset` and `blue` (or `text_color`) would also be far more readable.

Comment: Thanks @dan, I will try it

Comment: @dan It actually works very well.  And I can use `fs='\n'` rather than `fs=$'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the suggestion from @dan.  Instead of changing IFS, I use

```
printf "%s$fs" "${ctp}${aggr[@]:0:nk}${rst}"
```